# How do I prevent clearing out of a textfield when the user hits enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

As it stands at the moment, I am not autoselecting (See code below) on a bootstrap typeahead, this is working fine, but previously when a user hit enter it went with the autoselect[0], now it is clearing out the cell, what should I do to make it keep the current cell's content.

Code to disable autoselection and highlighting on bootstrap-typeahead.js as it stands right now:

```
$.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype.render = function (items) {
 var that = this;
 items = $(items).map(function (i, item) {
 i = $(that.options.item).attr('data-value', item);
 i.find('a').html(that.highlighter(item));
 return i[0];
});

this.$menu.html(items);
 return this;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/vvK3b/

Comment: Maybe I am missing the point - but I cannot see unwanted behavior in Firefox 21 here...

Comment: I am on chrome, it does not fill in when I hit enter it clears

Comment: I updated my js version, stil not working.

Comment: I am on boostrap 1.7, that might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stopped putting the class `active` on the highlighted item, but bootstrap doesn't know how to handle this. What you need to do is change the `select` function as well to not do what it does usually if there's no `active` class. Here is the code

```
$.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype.select = function () {
    if (this.$menu.find('.active').length) {
      var val = this.$menu.find('.active').attr('data-value')
      this.$element
        .val(this.updater(val))
        .change()
      return this.hide()
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/vvK3b/1/

Comment: Awesome, we are really close, now when I click the item it doesn't actually select it.

Comment: Hm, it selectes it for me (am using latest Chrome and trying the jsfiddle). Does the jsfiddle not work for you or your implementation? Which browser are you using?

Comment: Description:

I can now have typahead with no highlights.

I can now hit enter on typeahead and still keep text in the box.

I cannot select something in the typeahead and have it replace the content of the cell i was typing into.

Comment: You haven't really answered my questions. By your description, it still works for me in the jsfiddle in my answer and I've tried in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Ive tried in chrome, on my site it does not work. I can give you access to my site to see for yourself.

Comment: I am using bootstrap-typeahead.js v2.1.0

Comment: The jsfiddle uses bootstrap 2.3.2 so, if you can, try using that version on your site.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot, as I would have to upgrade my boostrap theme and I am waiting on 3.00 before I expend that much effort.

Comment: In that case, I would say that you have a problem that is beyond the scope of this answer. Good luck with trying to get the older bootstrap version to work. If you get stuck, feel free to email me, but I think SO is not the place for questions anymore.